# Django app switch from Mariadb to Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql, mariadb

I have changed the Django Settings file database engine to postgres_psycopg2.

When I run ./manage.py run server I get the following error numerous times:

```
"[03/Apr/2019 18:40:09] code 400, message Bad request version 
 ('error",
        "name":"DatabaseError",
    "code":"ECONNREFUSED",
    "property":null,
    "redirect":null,
    "errno":"ECONNREFUSED",
    "syscall":"connect",
    "address":"127.0.0.1",
    "port":3306,"fatal":true}}'
)
```

For some reason it is trying to connect to port 3306, which is the Mariadb port and not port 5432, which is the port for Postgresql.

I just upgraded my Mariadb to version 10.3.14 but the problem still exists.  My Postgresql is version 11.2.

I have been Googling for several days now and still  have not found a solution.

EDIT: I changed the "./manage.py runserver 192.168.1.109:8000/admin" and the error went away.  In my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file it had the bind_address set to the above ip address. I comment out that statement and now all is cool.

Comment: show settings.py db code